# Debug OOP javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have this javascript code that does not respond. I'd like to know how to add console.log or alert inside of them to be sure that the flow goes inside the methods. Is it possible ? I come from regular js :(

```
import Component from 'shared/component'; 
class TeacherShareAcademos {
  constructor(element) {
    this.$element = $(element);

    this.$form = this.$element.find('.teacherShareAcademos-form');
    this.$emailsInput = this.$element.find('.teacherShareAcademos-form-emails');
    this.$messageInput = this.$element.find('.teacherShareAcademos-form-message');
    this.$successAlert = this.$element.find('.teacherShareAcademos-form-flash--notice');
    this.$errorAlert = this.$element.find('.teacherShareAcademos-form-flash--alert');

    this.bindEvents();
  }

  bindEvents() {
    this.$form.on('ajax:send.teacherShareAcademos', $.proxy(this, 'handleSend'));
    this.$form.on('ajax:success.teacherShareAcademos', $.proxy(this, 'handleSuccess'));
    this.$form.on('ajax:error.teacherShareAcademos', $.proxy(this, 'handleError'));
  }

 unbindEvents() {
   this.$form.on('ajax:success.teacherShareAcademos');
   this.$form.on('ajax:error.teacherShareAcademos');
 }

 handleMessageSend() {
   this.resetAlerts();
   this.$successAlert.removeClass('hidden');
 }

 handleSend() {
   this.resetAlerts();
 }
}

TeacherShareAcademos.initialize = Component.initialize;
TeacherShareAcademos.unbindEvents = Component.unbindEvents;

export default TeacherShareAcademos;
```

Comment: Sure, you can just put the call where you want it to happen. Not sure what the issue / difficulty is here?

Comment: It's possible, but I'd recommend using breakpoints instead and watching the current context when you reach them. Any correct browser will provide this possibility.

Comment: My mistake, the file must not be called, that's why the console.log weren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put console.log on any line you want and as the code executes various functions, the console.log will print whatever you want.

For example:

```
unbindEvents() {
   console.log('unbindEvents called!');
   this.$form.on('ajax:success.teacherShareAcademos');
   this.$form.on('ajax:error.teacherShareAcademos');
 }
```